# What bitcoin core options can be changed without a restart?

Tags: bitcoin-core, nodes, bitcoin.conf

I often experiment with new bitcoin core options (like zmq, debug and fee options) and I would like to avoid restarting my node for them to take effect.

If I am not mistaken, changing the RPC password, for example, can be done without restarting the node but most options require a restart.

What are the options that require (and don't require) a restart to take effect?

Answer (score 3):

Debugging print options can be changed without a restart.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, won't accept it though, because I am hoping for a more complete answer.

Comment: That's the sum total of options you can change.

Comment: Are you sure those are the only ones? I'm disappointed, I was hoping there would be more.

Comment: The configuration options are things like how much memory can be allocated, how much caching to use, if peers should be sending transactions or not. Being able to configure these on the fly would come at an absurd cost of complexity, for very little in the way of use cases. What would you like to be configuring on the fly?

Comment: For now: zmq URLs and watermarks, maxmempool, mempoolexpiry, minrelaytxfee, maxuploadtarget

Comment: Wallets can be loaded/unloaded at runtime now (which is arguably changing the "wallet=" option).

Comment: I'm not sure I'd even consider loading wallets on the fly to meaningfully be different than taking down the node and adding it to the configuration. The majority of the time it will require a rescan, which hogs `cs_main`, and you desync from the network.

Comment: @PieterWuille that just reminded of 'addnode' which can be done with the corresponding RPC command.